# Order of sections in careers profile: "Apps & Software" should go way up!

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, jobs

I notice this new (?) section, "Apps & Software" on the careers profile. Well, this is the most important, by far, just after the personal statement! Should be even before experience and open source! And waaaay before StackExchange accounts!

Why? Because it's the ultimate summary of your achievements! Yes, you worked there - but what did you work on? Yes, you have some open source projects, but what are the main ones (the ones that have at least a home page - not just some stuff you keep in your GitHub).

Any way to change that?

Comment: Just allow users to specify the order they want their sections to appear?

Comment: Sure, that would be ideal.

Comment: We are going to avoid both these ideas for now (“Apps at top” and “custom ordering”). In the case of the former, what’s important will be different for each user (see [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130639/147667)). In the latter case, consistency across profiles is more important at the moment, and frankly we have other interface issues to solve first – like how friggin’ long the pages can get to be.

Answer (score 7):

> Because it's the ultimate summary of your achievements!

Says who? For one thing, most significant projects are a group effort. It's nice that you worked on Angry Birds or whatever, but just listing that doesn't say anything about your individual contribution. Conversely, you may have worked for quite a while on a project that was ultimately cancelled even though you did some great work. Furthermore, many (most?) software projects are in-house projects that nobody reading your résumé will have ever heard of, so what does listing such projects tell them?

The 'experience' section is the part where you get to explain what *you* have done on the projects you worked on, and that's what most prospective employers are likely to care about.

It *would* be nice if you could arrange the sections they way you want them, but I'd hate to see 'apps & software' elevated above 'experience' for everybody. I'd imagine that there's some appeal to keeping a standard order for Careers 2.0 résumés, so choosing your own order may not make sense.

Comment: In the "Apps" sections you also explain what *you* have done! Every app has "your role" field, where you can explain exactly what you did. If you only worked on in-house projects, no problem, don't add anything in this section and experience will show up first. My point is that *if* you add something that should go first, you shouldn't have to scroll through so much other stuff to get to it!